# Can't use enumerateLoadedClasses

Tags: java, frida

I successfully start frida server (with su) and attach it to the process without error. `Java.Interceptor` works fine, but I can't enumerate classes, I simply get `Unexpected end of block` error.

```
Java.perform(() => {
    Java.enumerateLoadedClasses({
        "onMatch": function(name) {
            console.log(name);
        },
        "onComplete": function() {
            console.log('Done!');
        }
    });
});
```

Then:

```
Error: Unexpected end of block
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1175)
    at forEach (native)
    at Ot (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1240)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:990)
    at _patchCode (native)
    at value (frida/runtime/core.js:163)
    at Dt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:991)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/memoize.js:4)
    at Fe (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:475)
    at _enumerateLoadedClassesArt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:108)
    at enumerateLoadedClasses (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:54)
    at <anonymous> (<input>:9)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:192)
    at <eval> (<input>:10)
    at eval (native)
    at fridaReplEvaluate (/repl.js:9)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:13)
    at c (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:23)
TypeError: cannot set property '_code' of null
    at Dt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:991)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/memoize.js:4)
    at Fe (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:475)
    at _enumerateLoadedClassesArt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:108)
    at enumerateLoadedClasses (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:54)
    at <anonymous> (<input>:9)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:192)
    at <eval> (<input>:10)
    at eval (native)
    at fridaReplEvaluate (/repl.js:9)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:13)
    at c (frida/runtime/message-dispatcher.js:23)
```

Why isn't working? More info:

```
 Android.........: 6.0.1
 Phone...........: Galaxy S5 Mini
 CPU ABI.........: armeabi-v7a
 Root access.....: Yes
 Java.available..: true
 Frida...........: frida-server-14.0.8-android-arm
```

Comment: Does it happen with all apps or only one specific app?

Comment: @Robert all apps.

Comment: Then there might be a bug in Frida. May the the old Android version is no longer tested. I would try to downgrade Frida to an older version (e.g. 12, 11 or older) and test again.

Comment: what does your python script look like?

Comment: Did you eventually manage to figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @auspicious99 Sorry for the delay, things happened here and I didn't have time to test, but what I found is that frida 10.6.24 is compatible with android 6. I didn't post it as an answer because it gave me an error when I installed it (dll error, probably because of the python version) and I couldn't test it.

Comment: @Kiritonito Thanks for replying with the interesting information. I have encountered the challenge of wanting to use different versions of frida and python for different projects (e.g., different phones), and found a very useful way of doing that is virtualenv, where I can have separate python environments on the same machine, each with its own python version and dependencies, and frida version too. Not sure, would this help you?